# MySql Inner Join Query with 7 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following tables.

```
cars
------------------------------------
¦ car_id  ¦ color_id  ¦ brand_id   ¦
------------------------------------
¦ 1       ¦ 1         ¦ 3          ¦
¦ 2       ¦ 2         ¦ 3          ¦
¦ 3       ¦ 1         ¦ 4          ¦
¦ 4       ¦ 3         ¦ 4          ¦
------------------------------------
colors
-----------------------
¦ color_id¦ color     ¦
-----------------------
¦ 1       ¦ red       ¦
¦ 2       ¦ blue      ¦
¦ 3       ¦ green     ¦
¦ 4       ¦ white     ¦
-----------------------
brands
-----------------------------------
¦ brand_id¦ brand    ¦ parent_id  ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 1       ¦ Toyota   ¦ 0          ¦
¦ 2       ¦ Nissan   ¦ 0          ¦
¦ 3       ¦ Sunny    ¦ 2          ¦
¦ 4       ¦ Corrola  ¦ 1          ¦
-----------------------------------
companies
---------------------------------
¦ company_id¦ name  ¦ location  ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 1         ¦ ABC   ¦ New York  ¦
¦ 2         ¦ XYZ   ¦ Florida   ¦
¦ 3         ¦ ASD   ¦ Texas     ¦
¦ 4         ¦ 3MM   ¦ Florida   ¦
---------------------------------
contacts
-----------------------------------
¦ contact_id¦ name   ¦ company_id ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 1         ¦ James  ¦ 1          ¦
¦ 2         ¦ Kevin  ¦ 1          ¦
¦ 3         ¦ Mic    ¦ 2          ¦
¦ 4         ¦ Nadia  ¦ 3          ¦
-----------------------------------
orders
---------------------------------------
¦ order_id  ¦ company_id ¦ contact_id ¦
---------------------------------------
¦ 1         ¦ 1          ¦ 1          ¦
¦ 2         ¦ 1          ¦ 2          ¦
¦ 3         ¦ 2          ¦ 3          ¦
¦ 4         ¦ 3          ¦ 4          ¦
---------------------------------------
order_items
---------------------------------------
¦ sn ¦ order_id  ¦ car_id    ¦ price  ¦
---------------------------------------
¦ 1  ¦ 1         ¦ 1         ¦ 100    ¦
¦ 2  ¦ 2         ¦ 2         ¦ 200    ¦
¦ 3  ¦ 3         ¦ 3         ¦ 100    ¦
¦ 4  ¦ 3         ¦ 4         ¦ 150    ¦
---------------------------------------
```

I am working on a web app in which I have these 7 tables which are inter connected.
I need a PHP MYSQL JOIN query which will list all cars which has been ordered in a table format with following columns:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦ Order ID ¦ Company Name  ¦ Contact Name ¦ Car Ordered         ¦ price  ¦
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦ 1        ¦ ABC           ¦ James        ¦ Nissan Sunny, Green ¦ 100    ¦
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please HELP!!

Comment: And where is your attempt to achieve such kind of result ?

Comment: note that the sn column in order_items is (presumably) redundant

Comment: I am new to mysql. i can write simple querries. i tried achieving this with nested querry but it didnt work... this is kind of rocket science for me

Comment: sn is unique key to serialize all items ordered because in some orders more than one item will be ordered in same order

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try with this query:

SELECT  orders.order_id as 'Order ID',
     companies.name as  'Company Name',
     contacts.name as 'Contact Name ', 
     CONCAT( brands.brand , ', ' ,colors.colcor) as 'Car Ordered',
     order_items.price as 'price'
     FROM order_items  
    left outer join orders on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
    left outer join contacts on orders.contact_id = contacts.contact_id 
    left outer join companies on orders.company_id  = companies.company_id
    left outer join cars on order_items.car_id =cars.car_id  
    left outer join colors on cars.color_id = colors.color_id
    left outer join brands on cars.brand_id = brands.brand_id
    order by brands.brand asc
```

Comment: Thank you. it works except the "car ordered" column. the car ordered column shows "0" zero in all rows. this column should show "parent brand, sub brand, color" i.e "Nissa, sunny, green"

Comment: previous example is MS-SQL sever, now add concat function for join

Comment: Now it shows the car ordered like "Sunny, red" but I want to see the car with the parent brand like "Nissan Sunny, red"

Comment: Hi, parent brand is different  id for "Nissan" and "Sunny".And for order just add order by column name